# Flickering/flashing in corner of eye and nausea when exposed to certain patterns

Tags: eye, opthalmology

Before I begin I'd like to say that I've already seen an ophthalmologist who has since referred me to a ophthalmic neurologist. I'm asking because this is freaking me out and I was hoping for some explanation. Preferably one I can take to my doctor and ask ``is this it?"

So the problem is that certain patterns will cause shimmering and flashing out of the corner of my left eye. It isn't an issue with my right eye. For what it's worth, I'm more near-sighted in my left eye, but I wear corrective lenses for that.

It kind of looks like this: https://youtu.be/QZYpEMp87Xo?t=21, but not exactly. As for what patterns trigger it, strait lines. Like you may find on jeans, on some coats (the lapel of my London Fog), other peoples striped dress shirts. Even words on a page can cause this to a lesser extent.

As for the nausea...it's nausea. It's not so bad that I'll vomit, but it's very unpleasant.

This doesn't happen unless triggered by the way, and the ophthalmologist said my eye is structurally sound.

To be clear, I'm not asking for advice. That's why I've seen one doctor already and he, in turn, has sent me to someone who specializes specifically in neurological conditions involving the eye/sight. I'm really just looking for some piece of mind as I wait.

Comment: Sorry, but we don't offer medical advice here. It's considered strictly off topic.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Aside from us not giving personal medical advice over the internet, there is no need to suggest to a specialist what condition you might have, especially if you are not a healthcare professional. Explaining your symptoms clearly and answering all of the doctor's questions should be sufficient help from your side.Freaking out before the examination, although understandable, isn't really going to help.

Comment: I'm not asking for medical advice. I'm seeing a doctor for that. I'm mostly looking for peace of mind. When you don't know what something may be it's scarier than if you have a name for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone feels unwell or headachy after looking at particular patterns, it's likely to be migraine.

> We investigated stripe-induced visual discomfort and its relation to migraine. Some people find viewing striped patterns aversive. Prior work has suggested that migraineurs, in particular, are bothered by stripes. Subjects were selected by opportunity sampling. They were shown striped patterns and asked questions about their general health and their headache history, if any. Of the 102 subjects, 38 were diagnosed as having migraine headaches, 22 had nonmigraine headaches, and 42 were considered to be nonheadache subjects; 82% of those with migraines were stripe sensitive while only 6.2% without migraines were stripe sensitive. We conclude that stripe aversiveness is related to migraine headaches and can assist differentiation of migraine and nonmigraine headaches.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2803073

Comment: Thank you very much! Given that I have a history of migraines (three different kinds including in the visual cortex/optic nerve and retina) this certainly sounds reasonable. Certainly better than a seizure, which is what I feared.

Comment: Seizure usually require strobing lights for induction.  Upvote if you think the answer helped you understand this phenomenon.

Comment: I tried when I first saw your answer. Unfortunately the best I can do mark it as my answer.